# Django REST framework not picking up API endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying to refactor an API to use the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I've changed my `urls.py` to the following (still in Django 1.11):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from .serializers import SessionSerializer
from .viewsets import SessionViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^api/v1\.0/feedback/$', SessionViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/profile/$', views.get_profile),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/update_profile/$', views.update_profile),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/update_password/$', views.update_password),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/sessions/$', views.get_session),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/user/$', views.get_user),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/sessions/send_schedule_request/$', views.send_schedule_request),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/sessions/confirm_session_time/$', views.confirm_session_time),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/password_reset/$', views.password_reset),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/me/apn/$', views.save_apn),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/confirm_activation_code$', views.confirm_activation_code),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/update_user_via_activation_code$', views.update_user_via_activation_code),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/questions/$', views.get_questions),
    url(r'^api/v1\.0/answers/$', views.save_answers),
    # url(r'^api/v1\.0/feedback/$', views.record_feedback),
    url(r'^session_types/$', views.session_types),
    url(r'^send_custom_notification/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.send_custom_notification, name='send_custom_notification'),
    url(r'^admin/lucy_web/send_session_time_notifications/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<session_id>\d+)/$', views.send_session_time_notifications, name='send_session_time_notifications'),

    url(r'^admin/lucy_web/app_activate/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.app_activate, name='app_activate'),
    url(r'^admin/lucy_web/create_activation_code/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.create_activation_code, name='create_activation_code'),
]
```

However, if I `python manage.py runserver` and go to `localhost:8000/api/v1.0/feedback/`, I get a 404 error response:

[image]

It seems like the `r'^api/v1\.0/feedback/` endpoint is not being picked up, even though it is passed as an argument to `router.register()`. Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added the default router urls back to the urlpatterns variable like this,

```
urlpatterns = [...]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Take a look at the usage section [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Comment: Indeed it seems I had forgotten to add `url(r'^api/v1\.0/feedback/$', include('rest_framework.urls')),` to `urlpatterns`. (I'm still getting other errors though, but the point is to `include` `rest_framework.urls`).